# hibernate lazy loading exception in context Spring JSF application

Tags: spring, hibernate, jsf, session, lazy-initialization

I'm working on a web application based on Spring, Hibernate and JSF and I'm facing a known problem that was discussed before several times. see below :

> 17:42:11,970 ERROR [STDERR] 7 nov. 2012 17:42:11 javax.faces.component.UIInput updateModel
>   GRAVE: createProjectForm:projectStatus: An error occurred when processing your   submitted information.
>       17:42:11,972 INFO  [STDOUT] 17:42:11 ERROR                    org.hibernate.LazyInitializationException                     could not initialize   proxy - no Session
>       org.hibernate.LazyInitializationException: could not initialize proxy - no Session
>           at   org.hibernate.proxy.AbstractLazyInitializer.initialize(AbstractLazyInitializer.java:57)
>           at org.hibernate.proxy.pojo.BasicLazyInitializer.invoke(BasicLazyInitializer.java:75)
>           at  org.hibernate.proxy.pojo.javassist.JavassistLazyInitializer.invoke(JavassistLazyInitializer.java:160)
>           at com.company.entity.TLsta_$$_javassist_6.setLStat(TLsta_$$_javassist_6.java)
>           at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
>           at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:39)
>           at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:25)
>           at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:597)
>           at javax.el.BeanELResolver.setValue(BeanELResolver.java:108)
>           at javax.el.CompositeELResolver.setValue(CompositeELResolver.java:68)
>           at com.sun.faces.el.FacesCompositeELResolver.setValue(FacesCompositeELResolver.java:100)
>           at org.apache.el.parser.AstValue.setValue(AstValue.java:114)
>           at org.apache.el.ValueExpressionImpl.setValue(ValueExpressionImpl.java:249)
>           at com.sun.facelets.el.TagValueExpression.setValue(TagValueExpression.java:93)
>           at javax.faces.component.UIInput.updateModel(UIInput.java:771)
>           at javax.faces.component.UIInput.processUpdates(UIInput.java:703)
>           at javax.faces.component.UIForm.processUpdates(UIForm.java:261)
>           at org.ajax4jsf.component.AjaxViewRoot$2.invokeContextCallback(AjaxViewRoot.java:419)
>           at org.ajax4jsf.component.AjaxViewRoot.processPhase(AjaxViewRoot.java:235)
>           at org.ajax4jsf.component.AjaxViewRoot.processUpdates(AjaxViewRoot.java:435)
>           at com.sun.faces.lifecycle.UpdateModelValuesPhase.execute(UpdateModelValuesPhase.java:78)
>           at com.sun.faces.lifecycle.Phase.doPhase(Phase.java:100)
>           at com.sun.faces.lifecycle.LifecycleImpl.execute(LifecycleImpl.java:118)
>       at javax.faces.webapp.FacesServlet.service(FacesServlet.java:265)
>           at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:290)
>           at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:206)
>           at org.ajax4jsf.webapp.BaseXMLFilter.doXmlFilter(BaseXMLFilter.java:178)
>           at org.ajax4jsf.webapp.BaseFilter.handleRequest(BaseFilter.java:290)
>           at org.ajax4jsf.webapp.BaseFilter.processUploadsAndHandleRequest(BaseFilter.java:388)
>           at org.ajax4jsf.webapp.BaseFilter.doFilter(BaseFilter.java:515)
>           at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:235)
>           at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:206)
>           at org.springframework.security.util.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:394)
>           at org.springframework.security.intercept.web.FilterSecurityInterceptor.invoke(FilterSecurityInterceptor.java:109)
>           at org.springframework.security.intercept.web.FilterSecurityInterceptor.doFilter(FilterSecurityInterceptor.java:83)
>           at org.springframework.security.util.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:406)
>           at org.springframework.security.ui.SessionFixationProtectionFilter.doFilterHttp(SessionFixationProtectionFilter.java:67)
>           at org.springframework.security.ui.SpringSecurityFilter.doFilter(SpringSecurityFilter.java:53)
>           at org.springframework.security.util.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:406)
>           at org.springframework.security.ui.ExceptionTranslationFilter.doFilterHttp(ExceptionTranslationFilter.java:101)
>           at org.springframework.security.ui.SpringSecurityFilter.doFilter(SpringSecurityFilter.java:53)
>           at org.springframework.security.util.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:406)
>           at org.springframework.security.providers.anonymous.AnonymousProcessingFilter.doFilterHttp(AnonymousProcessingFilter.java:10
>           at org.springframework.security.ui.SpringSecurityFilter.doFilter(SpringSecurityFilter.java:53)
>           at org.springframework.security.util.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:406)
>           at org.springframework.security.wrapper.SecurityContextHolderAwareRequestFilter.doFilterHttp(SecurityContextHolderAwareReque
>           at org.springframework.security.ui.SpringSecurityFilter.doFilter(SpringSecurityFilter.java:53)
>           at org.springframework.security.util.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:406)
>           at org.springframework.security.ui.AbstractProcessingFilter.doFilterHttp(AbstractProcessingFilter.java:278)
>           at org.springframework.security.ui.SpringSecurityFilter.doFilter(SpringSecurityFilter.java:53)
>           at org.springframework.security.util.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:406)
>           at org.springframework.security.ui.logout.LogoutFilter.doFilterHttp(LogoutFilter.java:89)
>           at org.springframework.security.ui.SpringSecurityFilter.doFilter(SpringSecurityFilter.java:53)
>           at org.springframework.security.util.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:406)
>           at org.springframework.security.context.HttpSessionContextIntegrationFilter.doFilterHttp(HttpSessionContextIntegrationFilter
>           at org.springframework.security.ui.SpringSecurityFilter.doFilter(SpringSecurityFilter.java:53)

I tried following solutions but without success :( :

- OpenViewInSession filter
- @Transactional annotation
- Hibernate.initialize(object)

I think my problem is related to JSF which could not get current Hibernate sesssion but I don't know how to resolve this.

I'm using :

- JSF 1.2
- Richfaces 3.3.2
- Spring 2.5
- Hibernate 3.2.5
- JBoss 4.2

Find below my config files and source code :

web.xml

```
<!-- Hibernate filter -->
<filter>
  <filter-name>hibernateFilter</filter-name>
  <filter-class>
      org.springframework.orm.hibernate3.support.OpenSessionInViewFilter
  </filter-class>
  <init-param>
      <param-name>sessionFactoryBeanName</param-name>
      <param-value>sessionFactory</param-value>
  </init-param>
</filter>
<filter-mapping>
  <filter-name>hibernateFilter</filter-name>
  <url-pattern>/*</url-pattern>
  <dispatcher>REQUEST</dispatcher>
    <dispatcher>FORWARD</dispatcher>
</filter-mapping>

<!-- Security --> 
<filter>
    <filter-name>springSecurityFilterChain</filter-name>
    <filter-class>org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy</filter-class>
</filter>
<filter-mapping>
    <filter-name>springSecurityFilterChain</filter-name>
    <url-pattern>/*</url-pattern>
    <dispatcher>FORWARD</dispatcher>
    <dispatcher>REQUEST</dispatcher>
    <dispatcher>ERROR</dispatcher>
    <dispatcher>INCLUDE</dispatcher>
</filter-mapping>
<!-- jsf listener -->
<listener>
    <listener-class>com.sun.faces.config.ConfigureListener</listener-class>
</listener>

<!-- spring listener -->
<listener>
    <listener-class>org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener</listener-  class>
</listener>
<listener>
    <listener- class>org.springframework.web.context.request.RequestContextListener</listener-class>
</listener>

<!-- jsf servlet -->
<servlet>
    <servlet-name>Faces Servlet</servlet-name>
    <servlet-class>javax.faces.webapp.FacesServlet</servlet-class>
    <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
</servlet>
<servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>Faces Servlet</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>*.jsf</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>

<!-- RichFaces login -->
<login-config>
    <auth-method>BASIC</auth-method>
</login-config>
```

ApplicationContext.xml

```
<!-- DataSource -->
<bean id="dataSource" class="org.springframework.jndi.JndiObjectFactoryBean">
    <property name="jndiName">
        <value>java:oracleDS</value>
    </property>
</bean>

<!-- Session Factory -->
<bean id="sessionFactory" class="org.springframework.orm.hibernate3.LocalSessionFactoryBean">
    <property name="dataSource">
        <ref bean="dataSource"/>
    </property>
    <property name="mappingLocations" value="classpath:*.hbm.xml" />

    <property name="hibernateProperties">
        <props>
            <prop key="hibernate.dialect">org.hibernate.dialect.Oracle10gDialect</prop>
            <prop key="hibernate.show_sql">false</prop>
        </props>
    </property>
</bean>

 <!-- Generic DAO -->
<bean id="genericDAO" class="com.company.dao.GenericDaoImpl">
    <property name="sessionFactory" ref="sessionFactory"/>
</bean>

<bean id="txManager" class="org.springframework.orm.hibernate3.HibernateTransactionManager">
        <property name="sessionFactory" ref="sessionFactory" />
</bean>

<tx:annotation-driven transaction-manager="txManager"/>

<bean id="genericManager" class="com.company.services.GenericManagerImpl">
    <property name="dao" ref="genericDAO"/>
</bean>

<context:component-scan base-package="com.company">
    <context:include-filter type="regex" expression="com.company.beans.projectdirectory.Maintain*"/>
    <context:include-filter type="regex" expression="com.company.beans.projectdirectory.services.ProjectDirectoryManager"/>
    <context:include-filter type="regex" expression="com.company.beans.app.*"/>
</context:component-scan>
<context:annotation-config />
```

Create.xhtml where there is acces to property that caused the error :

```
<rich:comboBox value="#{createProjectBean.project.TPsta.PStat}"id="projectStatus" selectFirstOnUpdate="false"  width="145"
required="true" requiredMessage="#{msg.CMP_requiredPrjStatusError}">
<f:selectItems  value="#{createProjectBean.projectStatusOptions}" />
</rich:comboBox>
```

Any idea what to do?

Comment: You need to post some of your config and code before we can help.

Comment: Please find above in my post my config files and source code

Answer (score 1):

Looks like you got this exception in 'UpdateModelValuesPhase' which happens before 'invoke application' phase. 'Invoke Application' phase is where you normally do most of the processing.

If you are using openSessionInView filter and still getting this exception, it is possible that you have loaded a proxy during previous request, but are trying to access it during current request. Since the proxy is associated with an old session that was closed, you get a LazyInitialization exception.

Comment: Your analysis seems logical and looks like this is the problem but how could I know if I loaded a proxy or not? or can you suggest me a solution?

Comment: You could use extended hibernate sessions that span 'long conversations'. You basically use the same hibernate session for the entire workflow by storing hibernate session in Http Session. But this could lead to other problems and in general better to avoid. Please see these links for details - http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/3.3/reference/en/html/transactions.html#transactions-basics-apptx https://community.jboss.org/wiki/OpenSessionInView#What_about_the_extended_Session_pattern_for_long_Conversations

Comment: Another solution is to -  identify the object from previous session that you are trying to load in the current session. First option, make sure that it is fully loaded in previous session so that you don't have to lazily load it in the current session. Second option, during the current request, use session.lock(Object) to re-associate the object with current session.

Comment: I tried the solution Hibernate sessions with long conversion but always I get the same error (may be it was a bad implementation of the solution).
For the second solution proposed, I didn't know where to put session.lock(object) but also I think it will not resolve the problem because the error was triggered when JSF was trying to UpdateModel so no java class was excecuted!!!